# Django raising 404 with a message

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views

I like to raise 404 with some error message at different places in the script eg: `Http404("some error msg: %s" %msg)`
So, in my urls.py I included:

```
handler404 = Custom404.as_view()
```

Can anyone please tell me how should I be handling the error in my views. I'm fairly new to Django, so an example would help a lot.
Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Since you overrode the `handler404`, design `404.html` and use `raise Http404`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In general, 404 error is "page not found" error - it should not have customizable messages, simply because it should be raised only when a page is not found.

You can return a [`TemplateResponse`](https://django.readthedocs.io/en/1.3.X/ref/template-response.html) with status parameter set to `404`

Comment: I think "it should not ..." is not an answer to above question. I think it is a valid use-case to get the message of `raise Http404(message)` into the final output.

Answer (score 11):

Generally there should not be any custom messages in 404 errors bu if you want to implement it you can do this using django middlewares.

**Middleware**

```
from django.http import Http404, HttpResponse


class Custom404Middleware(object):
    def process_exception(self, request, exception):
        if isinstance(exception, Http404):
            # implement your custom logic. You can send
            # http response with any template or message
            # here. unicode(exception) will give the custom
            # error message that was passed.
            msg = unicode(exception)
            return HttpResponse(msg, status=404)
```

**Middlewares Settings**

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'college.middleware.Custom404Middleware',
    # Uncomment the next line for simple clickjacking protection:
    # 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
)
```

This will do the trick. Correct me if I am doing any thing wrong. Hope this helps.

Comment: For some reason my middleware is not getting called with 404 errors, only 500 errors

Answer (score 9):

Raise an `Http404` exception inside a view. It's usually done when you catch a `DoesNotExist` exception. For example:

```
from django.http import Http404

def article_view(request, slug):
    try:
        entry = Article.objects.get(slug=slug)
    except Article.DoesNotExist:
        raise Http404()
    return render(request, 'news/article.html', {'article': entry, })
```

Even better, use [`get_object_or_404` shortcut](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/http/shortcuts/#get-object-or-404):

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404

def article_view(request):
    article = get_object_or_404(MyModel, pk=1)
    return render(request, 'news/article.html', {'article': entry, })
```

If you'd like to customize the default `404 Page not found` response, put your own template called `404.html` to the `templates` folder.

Answer (score 6):

Yes we can show specific exception message when raise Http404.

Pass some exception message like this

```
raise Http404('Any kind of message ')
```

Add 404.html page into templates directory.

templates/404.html

```
{{exception}}
```

Answer (score 3):

I figured out a solution for Django 2.2 (2019) after a lot of the middleware changed. It is very similar to Muhammed's answer from 2013. So here it is:

middleware.py

```
from django.http import Http404, HttpResponse

class CustomHTTP404Middleware:
    def __init__(self, get_response):
        self.get_response = get_response
        # One-time configuration and initialization.

    def __call__(self, request):
        # Code to be executed for each request before the view (and later middleware) are called.
        response = self.get_response(request)
        # Code to be executed for each request/response after the view is called.
        return response

    def process_exception(self, request, exception):
        if isinstance(exception, Http404):
            message = f"""
                {exception.args},
                User: {request.user},
                Referrer: {request.META.get('HTTP_REFERRER', 'no referrer')}
            """
            exception.args = (message,)
```

Also, add this last to your middleware in settings.py: `'app.middleware.http404.CustomHTTP404Middleware',`

Answer (score 2):

if you want to raise some sort of static messages for a particular view , you can do as follows:-

```
from django.http import Http404

def my_view(request):
  raise Http404("The link seems to be broken")
```

Comment: But how to get the message ("The link seems to be broken") into the final html?

Answer (score 1):

You can return a plain HttpResponse object with a status code (in this case 404)

```
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response

def my_view(request):
    template_context = {}

    # ... some code that leads to a custom 404

    return render_to_response("my_template.html", template_context, status=404)
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I wanted to take some action (e.g. logging) before returning a custom 404 page. Here is the 404 handler that does it.

```
def my_handler404(request, exception):
    logger.info(f'404-not-found for user {request.user} on url {request.path}')
    return HttpResponseNotFound(render(request, "shared/404.html"))
```

Note that `HttpResponseNotFound` is required. Otherwise, the response's HTTP status code is 200.

Answer (score 0):

The default 404 handler calls 404.html . You could edit that if you don't need anything fancy or can override the 404 handler by setting the handler404 view -- [see more here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/views/#the-404-page-not-found-view)