# Writing custom Exceptions in Django

Tags: python, django, exception

What I am trying to achieve is to make an object similar to `django.http.Http404` that I will able to call it with the `raise` command.

Use case:

```
def some_view(request):
    .
    .
    .. some code ..
    some_function()

    return HttpResponse("OK")

def some_function():
    .
    .
    .. some code ..

    if all_good:
        return ok_object
    else:
        raise MyCustomException("Mmm.. WRONG!", status=415)
```

What I'm trying to achieve is having this object receive some text, and a status code and make it plant this text on some template I have.

I thought about writing my own object, who would just return some kind of response, but this doesn't work in use cases like above of nested usage.
Also I don't want to check the returned object of `some_function` for its instance.

This seem pretty standard thing to do, so one will be able to attach his own template and operation for exceptions within django, but I Googled this pretty hard and all I find is how to customize the template.

Comment: try this if it helps you https://stackoverflow.com/a/16505694/5250746

Comment: doesn't quite help, some answers are about how to change text on 404, and some about just returning a custom response, which doesn't work on nested case :/ Also, I don't want to be bound to the 404 code

Comment: Using a middleware sounds like the right approach. In the answer @ArpitSolanki linked to, you would change `if isinstance(exception, Http404):` to `if isinstance(exception, MyCustomException):`. If you are using `MIDDLEWARE` in Django 1.10+, you would have to adjust for [new style middleware](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/http/middleware/).

Comment: @Alasdair checking the instance of the returned object is exactly what I don't want to do... in a real use case this could be 4 levels nested, I won't check every time what goes on with it... There must be a more elegant way for that :/

Comment: I'm not suggesting that you check the return value in any of your nested calls, you check the exception in the middleware, as in the linked answer.

Comment: I see the linked answer, i don't quite get how to use it in a manner where I can supply it when raising it with a custom code and message. If you know how to pull it off please post it as an answer explaining how to create and use it, and if it works I'll accept it

Comment: You're already raising a custom code `MyCustomException("Mmm.. WRONG!", status=415)`. In the middleware you can check `isinstance(exception, MyCustomException)` then access `exception.status_code`.

Comment: I'll try it out, I'll update here