# Is there a way to raise server status code as a client?

Tags: python, exception, python-requests, http-status-code-404

Sometimes due to poor server design, I get status code 200, when it should be different.

In such cases how can I myself on the client side raise the appropriate response (e.g. `404`). This will serve to mimic as if it were returned by the server?

I saw some [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16367374/django-raising-404-with-a-message/16415162) via `django`. Is this the only way?

Also I did not see anything of this sort in the standard python exceptions [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html). Why is such a thing not possible via the standard python exceptions?

Here is the way I handle this now:

```
import time

import aiohttp
import backoff


@backoff.on_exception(backoff.expo, aiohttp.ClientError, max_tries=5, max_time=5)
async def _fetch_url(session, url, msg_handler):
    downtime = 1
    while downtime < 60:
        async with await session.get(url, raise_for_status=True) as response:
            result = await msg_handler(response, url)
            # empty results means an error in request but status code 200.
            if len(result) == 0:
                downtime = downtime * 2
                time.sleep(downtime)
            else:
                return result
```

Comment: Are you running a web server on Python? If so, what server/library are you using?

Comment: No I am not. Sometimes when i make a url request (for data in json format) i get 200, but inside the json I get an error. In my case - I'd like to be able to manually raise a 404 in such cases.

Comment: When you say "url request", are you referring to a request from a client (e.g. `requests.get()`)?

Comment: Yes, exactly. It's a request to some API.

Comment: A client cannot raise a 404. This is something the server sends. If you make a request and receive 200, it means that the server has received and responded to your request correctly. If there is an error (from the client's side) relating to processing the response, this is not a 404 and is not related to the server at all. What is the problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: Well sometimes the API get too many requests (or is busy), etc and does not fetch me the data. But it does return a 200 status. Now I have fixed this by writing a exponential backoff inside my `fetch_url` function, but I also have an exponential backoff decorator to the function too - it triggers on 404. So I dislike that the code is not very clean - though it does work. I try to clean it up. If I could raise a 404 that would eliminate the need for the second exponential backoff which i wrote inside the function.

Comment: P.S. I did not know a client cannot raise a 404. Hence why my question may sound silly to many : ) Now I know.

Comment: I see. In this case, the server is supposed to respond with the proper status code (e.g. 500 or 504). If it is returning 200 on errors, that's a poor design on the server's side. As for the client, you need to find a different way to trigger the backoff function, e.g. raise an exception when the data has issues.

Comment: Okay go it. Thank you, Aziz! This was very informative and cleared up a lot o things I did not understand! I update my question to better reflect.

Comment: You are welcome. If you share the part of your code on how you're handling 404s and the decorator you use, we may find a clean solution that can work.

Comment: Will do that now. Thanks.

Comment: @Aziz, done. Let me know if you need more info.

Comment: Looking at your code, you don't need a 404. You just need to create an exception that the decorator will use. Just use `raise aiohttp.ClientPayloadError()` when the response has a problem. It will trigger the decorator.

Comment: That's as clean as it gets. Feel free to add as reply. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your code, it seems that you are trying to trigger an action that is supposed to be trigger when a request error happens. However, **status codes come from the server** and are **not controlled by the client**. If the server is returning a 200, it means that it has received and responded to your request correctly.

The decorator is trigger by any exception of type `aiohttp.ClientError`. So, to trigger it manually, you just need to raise an exception of that type (or of any its derived types). [Please refer to this page for the list of all `aiohttp` exceptions](https://docs.aiohttp.org/en/stable/client_reference.html#client-exceptions).

So, you can just use the following to raise an exception when you find an error in the server response:

```
raise aiohttp.ClientError('Server response is empty')
```

Answer (score -1):

Assuming you are running `SimpleHTTPServer`, the easiest way is to use [SimpleHTTP404Server](https://pypi.org/project/SimpleHTTP404Server/)

you can install it simple by runnning

```
pip install SimpleHTTP404Server
```

Browse to the directory, and run the following to server it on port 8000.

```
python -m SimpleHTTP404Server
```

An exception should fall into one of the following categories:

- Syntax Errors
- Handling Exceptions
- Raising Exceptions

Clearly you are looking for the solution in the wrong place. What you might be looking to do is to raise a **user-defined** exception according to certain criteria.

Consider the simple example below:

```
# define Python user-defined exceptions
class Error(Exception):
    """Base class for other exceptions"""
    pass


class ValueTooSmallError(Error):
    """Raised when the input value is too small"""
    pass


class ValueTooLargeError(Error):
    """Raised when the input value is too large"""
    pass


# you need to guess this number
number = 10

# user guesses a number until he/she gets it right
while True:
    try:
        i_num = int(input("Enter a number: "))
        if i_num < number:
            raise ValueTooSmallError
        elif i_num > number:
            raise ValueTooLargeError
        break
    except ValueTooSmallError:
        print("This value is too small, try again!")
        print()
    except ValueTooLargeError:
        print("This value is too large, try again!")
        print()

print("Congratulations! You guessed it correctly.")
```